# Find out if function has any output with php

Tags: php, function

Quick one for you guys.

Say I have a function that outputs a string:

```
function myString()
{
      echo 'Hello World';
}
```

How would I go about testing to see if the function outputs any data?

```
if(myString() ==''){ 
      echo ''Empty function;  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using output buffer functions:

```
function testFunctionOutput($f, $p = array()){
    ob_start();
    call_user_func_array($f, $p);
    $s = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush();
    return (bool)($s !== '');
}
```

So say...

```
function testa(){
  echo 'test';
}

function testb($b){
  $i = 20 * $b;
  return $i;
}

var_dump(testFunctionOutput('testa'));
var_dump(testFunctionOutput('testb', array(10)));
```

Alternative version suggested by Felix:

```
function testFunctionOutput2($f, $p = array()){
    ob_start();
    call_user_func_array($f, $p);
    $l = ob_get_length();
    ob_end_clean();
    return (bool)($l > 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 But to only test whether a function generates output, `ob_end_clean` is better suited than `ob_end_flush` imo. Instead of `ob_get_contents`, `ob_get_length` can be used too.

Comment: Thanks guys, but getting a "Warning: Missing argument 1 " error

Comment: Don't have functions echo output, return it instead.  That way you're more flexible to do stuff like this.  So when you just want to display it say  print myFunction();

Comment: @Keith - fixed. was the optional parameter issue.

Comment: @TravisO , I have no control over the function as it's generated from a plugin in WordPress :(

Answer (score 2):

Usually if a function returns data it will do so in a **return statement**.

as in

```
function myString() {

 $striing = 'hello';
 return $string;

}
```

To test it just call the function and see what it returns.

**If what you are asking is if something will be written to output as CT commented below ...  You will need to do something like this:**

```
//first turn out the output buffer so that things are written to a buffer
ob_start();

//call function you want to test... output get put in buffer.
mystring();

//put contents of buffer in a variable and test that variable
$string = ob_get_contents();

//end output buffer
ob_end()

//test the string and do something...
if (!empty($string)) {

 //or whatever you need here.
 echo 'outputs to output'
}
```

You can find out a lot more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking, see my other comment

Comment: Good point, CT, I've edited the suggestion to include that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Output BUffer should be the way to go as explained by thephpdeveloper.

---NOT RELEVANT---

```
if(!myString()){ 
  echo 'Empty function';
}
```

will echo 'Empty Function' when myString returns a value that can be evaluated to false IE:
o, false, null, "" etc...

```
if(myString() === NULL){ 
  echo 'Empty function';
}
```

Will only print 'Empty Function' when there is no return value.

Comment: This is a good answer for checking return values, but I don't think this answers what the OP was asking.  I think the OP wants to know if there is a way to determine if a function writes to the output stream.